# Angular specific way to determine scrolling direction

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll

Is there any angular specific way to determine if a user is scrolling upwards or downwards?
I came across solutions which all were either about jQuery or pure JavaScript.
I tried below JSFiddle but not getting it right, it always shows scrolling up.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/designaroni/sj3euzL7)

Here's how I tried it:

```
this.currentPosition = window.pageYOffset;

onContentScrolled(e) {
    let scroll = window.pageYOffset;
    if (scroll > this.currentPosition) {
      console.log('scrollDown');
    } else {
      console.log('scrollUp');
    }
    this.currentPosition = scroll;
}
```

The fiddle works all fine. But I want to know the correct way to implement in angular component.

It only outputs "scrollUp" every time. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here. I think it's with the global currentPosition variable but don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: hmm... your fiddle is actually working... i scroll down => it shows "Scrolling Down Scripts"... i scroll up => it shows "Scrolling Up Scripts"... is it supposed to do something different?

Comment: Yes the fiddle is absolutely right. but it is not working in my angular component. It always shows scrolling up (i.e else condition), maybe I am not converting the jQuery code correctly into angular component @Argee

Comment: oh, now i see...

Comment: try to print both values current position and scroll position in console... and check that your scroll position is always less than your current position.

Comment: I will try, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I have lot more complex structure in my app, which includes dynamic content from various components, so I tried below and it worked seamlessly!

```
private scrollChangeCallback: () => void;
currentPosition: any;
startPosition: number;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.scrollChangeCallback = () => this.onContentScrolled(event);
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollChangeCallback, true);
}

 onContentScrolled(e) {
  this.startPosition = e.srcElement.scrollTop;
  let scroll = e.srcElement.scrollTop;
  if (scroll > this.currentPosition) {
    this.showButton = false;
  } else {
    this.showButton = true;
  }
  this.currentPosition = scroll;
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollChangeCallback, true);
}
```

> e.srcElement works like a charm!

And thanks for all solutions above! They weren't wrong just didn't fit to my app

Comment: Do not forget to `removeEventListener` on `ngOnDestroy`. You don't want to have a memory leakage.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where you want to add the listener (to a specific component, to the document, to the body, etc). A silver bullet is to use a regular event listener. As an example let's listen to scrolling events on the document. You can inject the `document` in the constructor (just in case you want to use something like SSR in the future):

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackblitzcomedithttpsstackoverflowcoma6167905864331660?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

```js
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document) {
  this._document.addEventListener('scroll', this.onContentScrolled);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this._document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onContentScrolled);
}

onContentScrolled = (e) => {
  let scroll = window.pageYOffset;
  if (scroll > this.currentPosition) {
    console.log('scrollDown');
  } else {
    console.log('scrollUp');
  }
  this.currentPosition = scroll;
}
```

If you want to do the same thing with the scrollbar contained within a component, you can use the `@HostListener('scroll')` to decorate the listener method inside the component you want to listen to scrolling events.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma6167905864331661?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

```js
@HostListener("scroll", ['$event.target'])
onContentScrolled(e: HTMLElement) {
  let scroll = e.scrollTop;
  if (scroll > this.currentPosition) {
    console.log("scrollDown");
  } else {
    console.log("scrollUp");
  }
  this.currentPosition = scroll;
}
```

Comment: It's strange, your stackblitz works absolutely fine, but when I tried both the above technique, it still didn't work in my case

Comment: The first technique or the second one (with `@HostListener`)?

Comment: both! I think it is because of the complex app structure I have

Comment: You have to discover exactly where the scrollbar is attached to. Probably it's not the `document` nor the host component. Maybe the `<body>`... you have to inspect your app using dev tools to find out. And add the event listener to that component that the scrollbar is attached to.

Comment: Ya I will debug it and check

Answer (score 2):

my observable version of it: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-boofq6)

Comment: the event didn't get fired

Comment: in my example i've set `html, body {height:300%;}` in the `style.css`... maybe that's an issue?

Comment: It's probably a matter of observing the right component (the one that owns the scrollbar)

Comment: yes could be that, and it was fine. i didn't apply css from solution.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is pretty late, but here's what worked for me in angular 9.

Typescript

```js
lastScrollTop = 0
scrollHandler(event) {
  let currentScrollTop = event.currentTarget.scrollTop
  if (currentScrollTop > this.lastScrollTop) this.handleScrollDown()
  else this.handleScrollUp()
  this.lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop
}
```

```html
HTML
<div class="container border" (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this work like a charm for me using Angular 13

----------------------------HTML CODE------------------------------------------------

```
 <div class="list"
 (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
     here you list or content to paginate /scroll
 </div>
```

-----------------------------TS CODE---------------------------------------------------

```
startPosition: number = 0; //global variable

onScroll(event: any) {

if (
  this.startPosition <=
  event.target.offsetHeight + event.target.scrollTop + 50
) {
  console.log('scrolled down!!', event);
} else {
  console.log('scrolled up!!', event);
}
this.startPosition =
  event.target.offsetHeight + event.target.scrollTop + 50;
}
```

TO DO refactor ,Hope this helps you ,have a nice coding ^^

Comment: Why add 50 in the calculation?

Comment: you can delete it  ,i added  50 for some css margin needs .

Answer (score 1):

I know this issue is old but just want to share my solution to detect scrolling direction for specific element using angular directive + rxjs.

Here the my directive example:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[scrollDirection]',
    exportAs: 'ScrollDirectionDirective',
})
export class ScrollDirectionDirective implements OnDestroy {
    /**
     * Emit scroll direction change event outside of the direction
     */
    @Output() scrollDirectionChanged: EventEmitter<ScrollDirection> = new EventEmitter();

    /**
     * Stream of current element scroll direction
     */
    scrollDirection$: Observable<any>;

    /**
     * Current native element
     */
    nativeElement: HTMLElement;

    /**
     * Scroll direction stream subscription
     */
    sub: Subscription;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param elementRef ElementRef
     */
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.nativeElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        this.scrollDirection$ = fromEvent<Event>(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'scroll')
            .pipe(
                map((event: Event) => event?.target as HTMLElement),
                map<HTMLElement, DetectScrollDirectionPayload>(el => ({ scrollTop: el?.scrollTop, scrollLeft: el?.scrollLeft })),
                startWith({ scrollTop: 0, scrollLeft: 0 }),
                distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => a.scrollLeft === b.scrollLeft && a.scrollTop === b.scrollTop),
                pairwise(),
                map(([payload1, payload2]) => ({ vertDelta: payload2.scrollTop - payload1.scrollTop, horDelta: payload2.scrollLeft - payload1.scrollLeft })),
                map(res =>
                  res.vertDelta !== 0
                    ? res.vertDelta > 0
                        ? ScrollDirection.Down
                        : ScrollDirection.Up
                    : res.horDelta !== 0
                        ? res.horDelta > 0
                            ? ScrollDirection.Right
                            : ScrollDirection.Left
                        : null,
                ),
                share(),
            );

        this.sub = this.scrollDirection$.pipe(
            distinctUntilChanged(),
        ).subscribe(res => {
            this.scrollDirectionChanged.next(res);
        })
    }

    /**
     * NG Hook
     */
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub?.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

And then we can simply use this directive anywhere to detect scroll direction:

```
<div #scrollDirection="ScrollDirectionDirective" scrollDirection class="scroll-container">
  <div class="title">{{ (scrollDirection.scrollDirection$ | async) | json }}</div>
  <div class="scroll-content"></div>
</div>
```

Full working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bayuvh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fscroll-direction%2Fscroll-direction.directive.ts

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
lastScrollTop = 0;
hold = false;

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document) {
 this._document.addEventListener('scroll', this.onContentScrolled);
}

  onContentScrolled(e) {
const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
const st = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 200) {
  this.mainSectionOneIndex = 0;
}
if (st > this.lastScrollTop) {
  if (this.hold === false) {
    this.hold = true;
    console.log('down');
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.hold = false;
    }, 500);
  }
} else {
  if (this.hold === false) {
    this.hold = true;
    console.log('up');
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.hold = false;
    }, 500);
  }
}
this.lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st;
}
```